# Add new object to State Array, if duplicate then update object key. React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add Object to my array, if not found in the array. If found just update answer.

I have 5 object to store in array.

*The function below checks selected state, if there's an object then it maps through and if an object question === question that's passed... it changes the answer to the new selected answer.
else if [selected] state is empty it pushes new array (the last line), So if there's one object, how do i add more to my [selected] keeping ...prevState.*

```
function select(answers, question, correct_answer){

     setSelected(
                    selected 
                     ?
                    selected.map(item => {
                             if(item.question === question){
                                 return {...item, answers: answers}
                             }
                             return item
                    })
                    :
                    [{answers, question, correct_answer}]
                )
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
function select(answers, question, correct_answer){
 if(!selected) {
   setSelected([{answers, question, correct_answer}])
   return
 }     
 if(selected.some(item => {
                  if(item.question === question) {
                     item.answers = answers 
                     return true
                  }})) { 
    setSelected(items)
 }
 else setSelected([...items, {answers, question, correct_answer}])   
}
```

Comment: This will keep adding objects, creating duplicates.

Comment: I've updated my answer @memerem, no special magic exists.